# ImageView width to be 50 percent of Device width Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-cardview

before I start I should say that I'm a beginner in Android development :)
I am using a Grid `recyclerView` and have set the number of columns to 2.
I only have one `ImageView` in my `cardView` and I don't know how to make this card (or Image) to be 50% of screen width, because when I set its height and width with numbers then I get problems on different screen sizes.

I read and tried some ways with `layout_weight` but it doesn't work with this `cardView`.

> card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_photo_double_view"
        android:src="@drawable/e48"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do that here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `CardView` extends from `FrameLayout`. if you really want to use `CardView`, put a `LinearLayout` inside CardView, then you can use attr layout_weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such things have appered in ConstraintLayout. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).

Without using this library i can only suggestion you using `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see. I use `android:weight` attribute of `LinearLayout` to make ImageView take 50% of screen width if linearlayout takes the whole screen.

There is no need to define `weight_sum` in LinearLayout, just simply use `layout_weight` in child layout and assign the value. And be sure to set the `height` or `width` to 0, if you want to make the partitions vertically or horizontally respectively.

PS. `layout_weight` works with LinearLayouts only.

Answer (score 1):

By using percent relative layout, we can achieve this easily. Herewith I will explain how to implement the `percentRelativeLayout`.

**Dependency:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
```

In your layout file,

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="match_parent"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Hope this is helpful:)